# error of function replay in DolphinDB: inputTables must be one or a tuple of non segmented tables|DataSources

Tags: stream, dolphindb, replay

error message:
inputTables must be one or a tuple of non segmented tables|DataSources
Usage: replay(inputTables, outputTables, [dateColumn], [timeColumn], [replayRate], [absoluteRate=true], [parallelLevel=1]). inputTables must be one or a tuple of non segmented tables|DataSources

```
replay(inputTables=currency_table,outputTables=currency_result)
```

I run the script and it reported an error. Both tables are stream tables. How can I replay DFS tables?

Answer (score 0):

The `inputTables=currency_table` here is a stream table. Currently, the stream table is not supported as the input table for replay in DolphinDB. You can load it to an in-memory table.
To replay data of a partitioned table, you can use the replayDS function. See details at https://www.dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/r/replayDS.html